# Telephonebook in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have this code here:

```
type Name = String
type Number = String
type Phonebook = Name -> Number

emptyPhonebook :: Phonebook 
emptyPhonebook = \x -> "not found"

fillIn :: Name -> Number -> Phonebook -> Phonebook 
fillIn name number book = \add -> if name == add then number else book add
```

My question is, what exactly is meant with the `\add` in the `fillIn` function and how exactly does the whole line in this function work?

When I'm running the code and try to run one of the functions i get the error:

```
No instance for (Show Phonebook) arising from a use of `print'
```

How to change that?

Comment: Well the error is clear: if you construct a new `Phonebook` in the shell, `ghci` wants to `print` the book, but it does not know how since `Name -> Number` is a function and it asks you to define an `instance Show` to print it.

Comment: This looks like homework.

Comment: The `print` function doesn't appear in your code.

Comment: @chepner: I think he runs it in `ghci` and `ghci` aims to print the result of a `fillIn` call and thus fails to print it.

Comment: @DanielWagner There's actually a few. If you search "Phonebook Haskell" (capital P required), a solid list comes up. I not sure which is the best to close as a dupe as. They'll all basically the same

Comment: @DanielWagner I should have specified. This homework question has been asked a few times before. It's not necessarily the same question the OP has though. Sorry, wasn't paying attention

Answer (score 5):

The `\add -> ...` is a **lambda expression**. A lambda expression is an anonymous function that here takes one argument `add` and maps it on `...` (here `if name == add then number else book add`). You could have given the poor child a name (for instance `newbook`) and write it like:

```
fillIn :: Name -> Number -> Phonebook -> Phonebook
fillIn name number book = newbook
    where newbook add = if name == add then number else book add
```

or more elegantly:

```
fillIn :: Name -> Number -> Phonebook -> Phonebook
fillIn name number book = newbook
    where newbook add | name == add = number
                      | otherwise = book add
```

Now the `add` is a bit confusing, a better name would be `query` I guess, since the new phone book `newbook` takes as input a query and aims to find a phone number.

The function is thus given a new `name` and `number` and an old `book`. It constructs a new phone book `newbook` that, when queried first checks whether the query corresponds to our newborn `name` and if that is the case returns his `number`, and otherwise will pass the query to the `book` (the old phone book) and lets figure it out by that book.

Your `emptyPhonebook` of course has no numbers so regardless of what query you give it, it returns `"not found"`.

The reason Haskell cannot `print` the phonebook, is because it does not know how. In order to print an object, it has to be an instance of `Show` (and thus implement the `show` function.

On the other hand I don't know if it is wise to represent a phone book as a function mapping names on numbers, since perhaps you want to find the stalker that once tried to contact you (and thus make a reverse lookup). Perhaps a better way here is to use a list of tuples `[(Name,Number)]`, or even better use hashtables.

Comment: Worth noting that [difference lists](https://wiki.haskell.org/Difference_list) use a similar idea, using continuation passing style to build up a function recursively. `append item continuation = \rest -> continuation (item:rest)`. In that case you first build up all these append operations into one large function before applying them in one go which lets you append n items in O(n) instead of O(n^2)!

Comment: @Taren: I don't really see the relevance of this comment here. We do not append nor apply any functin to a list since this is not a list (but a function). I know what a difference list is: I've written [four answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A67579+difference+lists) on them. They are useful for for instance grammar parsing. But in what way are they relevant here?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't trying to insinuate that you didn't know about them. I just figured that the exercise probably was a play on them since it also involves transforming data into a function using cps. I also find them really cool from a conceptual standpoint and thought that some people confused by the fillin function might not have heard about them yet.

Comment: @Taren: it was not the point that your comment was (it wasn't) insulting. Indeed difference lists are a cool mechanism in both functional and logic programming. The point is however that one can write a 500-pages textbook on everything you can do with functions and lists, etc :). Although these are cool, they are not really relevant to *this* question specifically as far as I know :).